# Delete tuple in a list according highest value of second index

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of tuples such as :

```py
a_list = [(1, 0.5), (1, 0.1), (1, 0.9), (2, 0.4), (2, 0.8)]
#or
a_list = [(1, 0.5), (1, 0.9), (1, 0.1), (2, 0.8), (2, 0.4)]
```

I would like update the list according **the highest value of second index**.
To have:

```py
a_list = [(1, 0.9), (2, 0.8)]
```

Is this possible? Thanks.

---

Based on @lifezbeautiful here is a solution:

```py
list(dict(sorted(a_list)).items())
```

`sorted` ensures that the last tuple contains the highest values.

Comment: just clarifying if I understand it correctly, you want to update according to the most recent value?

Comment: `[list[2], list[4]]`…?

Comment: @lifezbeautiful Yes I would update the list according to highest values of the two indices of each tuple.

Comment: @Tim I think it you could show another example or clarify it would be clear whether you are trying to retain the maximum value or the maximum index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict()` to convert the list of tuples to a dictionary. The list of tuples will be parsed as a list of {`key`:`value`} pairs. In the second step, we revert back to the list of tuples using `.item()`. I changed the variable name to `a`, because `list` is a keyword and it can cause trouble later in your code if you use it as a variable.

```
a = [(1, 0.5), (1, 0.1), (1, 0.9), (2, 0.4), (2, 0.8)]
print (list(dict(a).items()))

# output:  [(1, 0.9), (2, 0.8)]
```

The snippet works for both python2.x and 3.x

Comment: This only works if the highest value is the last of each key, and even then I'm not sure it's always guaranteed…

Comment: @deceze this is exactly the behavior that the OP wants: "_would update the list according to highest values of the two indices of each tuple_ "

Comment: Depends on how they define "highest" then. Does that mean *last*? Or perhaps highest value of second index?

Comment: @deceze I think the OP meant "highest"="last". This requirement is common in many practical applications, hence I concluded this is what the OP meant. Hope the OP clarifies this.

Comment: Thanks all. I edited **a** solution. @deceze Do you have an example of a situation where this would not work?

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
list = [(1, 0.5), (1, 0.1), (1, 0.9), (2, 0.4), (2, 0.8)]
list.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]), reverse=True)

done = []
output = []
for l, r in list:
    if l not in done:
        done.append(l)
        output.append((l, r))

print(output)
```

Comment: FWIW, `key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1])` can be omitted entirely for the same effect…

Comment: @deceze thanks for pointing that one out. I was just overthinking at that moment. :)